# Is std::map access thread safe if iterators to it are never invalidated

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

So I want to generate a map like so: `std::map<std::string, std::atomic<bool>>`. My use case is some run-time checks to see if certain conditions are met (true or false); and I cache the result of the conditions check in this map since those checks are expensive.

The idea would be that I pre-populate this map with a `std::call_once`, and then never remove or insert elements again. However, I would have concurrent access to it via find() and those accesses might change the value of the `std::atomic` values using store(true).

Now I am wondering if this is thread safe? I must admit I feel like I am in undefined behaviour territory here.

Comment: Provided your map is fully built before multiple threads start searching it, that will be fine.

Comment: Be aware that the `[]` operator ***may*** modify the map, so all bets are off if
 it's used. Provided that the map is never modified, this is safe; and the best way to make sure it's safe is to make sure that a compilation error occurs if not. This can be easily done to make sure that the map is always `const`, after construction. The best way to ensure it is to make it a `const` class member, and fully create it in the class's constructor's initialization section. This will prove that the map is always const, cannot be modified, and is thusly thread safe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think they can let the map be const, considering they intend to modify the mapped (atomic) values.

Comment: That can be worked around by making the map's value a class with the atomic flag as a mutable class member.

Answer (score 1):

> Is std::map access thread safe if iterators to it are never invalidated

This is not a sufficient precondition. Insertions do not invalidate iterators, but do introduce a race with other accessing threads.

> The idea would be that I pre-populate this map

This seems sufficient. It is safe to concurrently read (find, traverse, etc.) a standard map from multiple threads as long as no thread modifies it.

> and those accesses might change the value of the `std::atomic`

Accessing, even writing an atomic object is also thread safe. But do keep in mind that a sequence of multiple atomic operations is not atomic as a whole.